# How to check if an oracle remote database is online?

Tags: database, oracle, dblink

I have a db link from DB1 to DB2. I have a job that runs a procedure that uses the contents on DB2, however, I would like the procedure to first check if DB2 is online and the dblink is working, if not then stop exit the procedure. Is there a function or command that checks if the remote database is online?

Comment: `select * from dual@dblink`

Comment: The gives me a tns error. How can I implement that into plsql block for an if...then case.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare 
  a int; 
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(0) from dual@dblink' into a;
  -- DBlink online
exception
  -- DBlink offline
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

My DBA recommended checking the output from
    sqlplus user/passwd `<<EOF`
    select sysdate from dual ;
    EOF